# How can I make an animation like this in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I am trying to make this kind of animation, where the user has to complete some steps to be able to do a transfer, the page has 4 steps and each step unlocks and slides vertically after completing the previous step.

For example, here the user has to specify the destination and in the destination section we can see the section to specify the amount, but it is blocked until the user specifies the destination.

[Video sample](https://youtube.com/shorts/dwkqu1-ply4?feature=share)

[image]

After the user selects the destination, the amount section unlocks and slides up and now the user can specify the amount and so on.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide video or example of animation?

Comment: Of course, here is the video  https://youtube.com/shorts/dwkqu1-ply4?feature=share